# Http Post from Web form with Attachment to force.com VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, site.com

we want to create Contact us page in our website to post contact details from web page to Salesforce and create contact with details just like standard functionality of webtolead. We are able to create contact from web page but also we want to post Attachment as well.

Can anyone please help me how to post attachment from web form Force.com Vf page and how to accept this attachment in Apex controller .Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `apex:inputFile` element is what you need. There is sample code here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputFile.htm

But a much more complete and probably more relevant example to your use case is here:

http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/04/22/uploading-a-document-using-visualforce-and-a-custom-controller/

In summary, you create a Document exposed by your custom controller and bind your `apex:inputFile` to that Document

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apex:inputFile` tag in vf page for this feature.[Click here for reference.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputFile.htm)